# Bounding the dimension of the image of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$\newcommand{\Im}{\mathrm{Im}}$

Let $T,S:V \to E$ be linear transformations, with $r(T) = \dim\Im (T)$. Prove that:

> $$\big| r(T) - r(S)\big| \le r(T+S) \le r(T) + r(S).$$

The second inequality is "easy" to prove, since it holds:
$$\dim\Im(T+S) \le \dim\big[\Im (T)+\Im (S)\big] \tag{1},$$
due to $\Im(T+S) \subseteq \Im(T) + \Im(S)$.
Moreover, it can be proven that for any two subspaces $W_1,W_2\subseteq E$ it holds:
$$\dim(W_1 + W_2) = \dim(W_1) + \dim(W_2) - \dim(W_1 \cap W_2)\tag{2}.$$

Considering $W_1 = \Im (T)$ and $W_2 = \Im (S)$ by $(2)$ we have:
$$\dim\big[\Im(T) + \Im(S)\big] \le \dim\Im(T) + \dim\Im(S)= r(T) + r(S)\tag{3}.$$

Combining $(1)$ and $(3)$, we have that:
$$r(T+S) \le r(T) + r(S).$$

However, I do not know how to deal with the first inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose $r(T) \ge r(S)$ (without loss of generality).

Then we have to prove $r(T)-r(S) < r(T+S)$, which is $r(T) < r(S)+r(T+S)$. This holds because $T = T+S + (-S)$ and $r(S)=r(-S)$.

Comment: Just simple... I've been expecting something more complicated. :Ρ

Answer (score 1):

You've shown that $r(T+S)\le r(T)+r(S)$. Applying that to a different pair of linear transformations shows that $r(T)\le r(S)+r(T+S)$. And also $r(S)\le r(T)+r(T+S)$.